# Running Tensorflow with tensorflow-metal in a docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

Is there a way to run TensorFlow with Apple's Metal GPU support in a Docker container?

Apple has described the instructions for installing GPU support [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

Comment: Doesn't look like it would work without trying to compile anything yourself: [apple/tensorflow_macos](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/164)

Comment: Docker assumes a Linux OS so tensorflow-metal isn't going to run in such an environment.  One reason why people might be asking this question is to somehow escape Apple's annual developer breakage.